# Placing information from an xml file into a listbox

Tags: c#

Here is what I have. I would expect the xml file to appear in the listbox after the user selects a term. However the screen just goes blank. I have another xml file that works perfectly fine with the code I have, but I need it to work for this xml file. It is very large so I thought maybe that could be a reason for it not working. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Xml;

namespace PhoneApp5
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemLine1 { get; set; }
        public string ItemLine2 { get; set; }
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PageTitle.Text = "Terms";
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        Item item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = "Third Summer 2013";
        item.ItemLine2 = "Classes";
        list.Add(item);
        item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = "Second Summer 2013";
        item.ItemLine2 = "Classes";
        list.Add(item);
        item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = "First Summer 2013";
        item.ItemLine2 = "Classes";
        list.Add(item);
        item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = "Spring 2013";
        item.ItemLine2 = "classes";
        list.Add(item);
        item = new Item();
        item.ItemLine1 = "Fall 2012";
        item.ItemLine2 = "Classes";
        list.Add(item);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ListBox1.ItemsSource = list));

    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       ApplicationTitle.Text = e.Result;
    }

    private void ListBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (sender != null) PageTitle.Text = sender.ToString();
        //if (e != null) PageTitle.Text = e.AddedItems.Count.ToString();

        //IEnumerator ie = e.AddedItems.GetEnumerator();
        //ie.MoveNext();
        //if (e != null) ApplicationTitle.Text = ie.Current.ToString();

         WebClient wc = new WebClient();
         wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
         wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.usi.edu/webservices/iphone/USIINFO201310.xml"));


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to load the XML?  I see you request it, but I'm not seeing you do anything with it once it's back.  You're just trying to set the title to the e.Result.  Is that setting the title to the whole XML?

Comment: Well when I change it to another small xml file, the xml displays on the entire screen of the windows phone emulator. I think the one that I need to display is just too large. I got an OutOfMemoryException